# Function that should return structure pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

I am grappling with structure pointers and their usage in functions. Here, I have a problem. The code below isn't printing the ID, name, and score which I would like it to print. I spent hours trying to figure this out. Can anyone please explain it in an easy-to-understand way?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
struct examinee
{
    char ID[8];
    char name[32];
    int score;
};
 
struct examinee* init(char ID[8], char name[32], int score){
    struct examinee* instance; 
    instance = (struct examinee*)malloc(sizeof(struct examinee));
    strcpy(instance->ID, ID);
    strcpy(instance->name, name);
    instance->score;
    return  instance;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct examinee examinee_1;
    struct examinee* examinee_1_ptr = init("IO760","Abe",75);
    examinee_1_ptr= &examinee_1;
    printf("examinee's information:\nID: %s\nname: %s\nscore: %d\n", examinee_1_ptr->ID, examinee_1_ptr->name, examinee_1_ptr->score);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
struct examinee* examinee_1_ptr = init("IO760","Abe",75);
```

you execute the function and store the result in the `examinee_1_ptr` variable.

But then these two lines

```
struct examinee examinee_1; 
examinee_1_ptr= &examinee_1;
```

create an empty `examinee` instance and override the pointer with the address of that blank instance. At this point, the one you created in `init()` is lost, because nothing is pointing at its address anymore so you have no way to access it. Remove those two lines and you'll be fine.

```
printf("examinee's information:\nID: %s\nname: %s\nscore: %d\n", examinee_1_ptr->ID, examinee_1_ptr->name, examinee_1_ptr->score);
```

Note that here you are only accessing the object through the pointer. There is no need to have the `examinee_1` variable in the first place.

Comment: Also, the line `instance->score;` does not do anything. Did you mean an assignment: `instance->score = score;`?